# How to export, import, and run custom model in tf2?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, text-classification, tensorflow-serving

I am training a custom text classification model using tf2 on a dummy data. The model seems to train fine. Then I export it. Then I am having issues importing it and running the model that I had saved.

Also, I am not sure where the vocabulary and tokens are getting saved.

```
import tensorflow as tf
print("tf.__version__: ", tf.__version__)
import os, sys, random
from pprint import pprint
import numpy as np

# CONFIGURATION
START_EPOCH = 0 
END_EPOCH = 3
MAX_LENGTH = 5
BATCH_SIZE = 256
WORD_EMB_DIM = 32
LSTM_DIM=32
SAVE_MODEL_PATH = "saved_models/1"

# DUMMY DATA  
text_data = [
        "i like this movie",
        "i feel happy watch movie",
        "great taste",
        "like the look of it",
        "great news",
        "hate this movie",
        "very bad news",
        "horrible movie",
        "very bad news",
        "i do not like it"
        ]

label_data = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]


# BUILD DATASET
class text_dataset():
    def __init__(self):
        self._build_vocab()
        
    def _build_vocab(self):
        words = []
        for words_list in [t.split(" ") for t in text_data]:
            words.extend(words_list)
        words = sorted(list(set(words)))

        self.item2idx = {}
        self.item2idx["<pad>"] = 0
        for w_idx, w in enumerate(words):
            self.item2idx[w] = w_idx + 1
        
        self.idx2item = {w_idx: w for w, w_idx in self.item2idx.items()}
        self.vocab_size = len(self.idx2item)
        print("self.vocab_size: ", self.vocab_size)

    def data_generator(self):
        batch_idx = 0
        while batch_idx < 8:
            sample_indices = [random.randint(0, len(text_data)-1) for _ in range(BATCH_SIZE)]

            x_raw = [text_data[i] for i in sample_indices]
            y = [label_data[i] for i in sample_indices]
            x_raw = [i.split(" ") for i in x_raw]                       
            x_raw = [[self.item2idx[j] for j in i] for i in x_raw]        
            zero_array = np.zeros((BATCH_SIZE,  MAX_LENGTH))        
            for i in range(len(x_raw)):
                zero_array[i, :len(x_raw[i])] = x_raw[i]   
            x_train = np.array(zero_array) # (BATCH_SIZE, MAX_LENGTH)
            y_train = np.array(y)          # (BATCH_SIZE, )
            yield tuple((x_train, y_train))
            batch_idx += 1

# BUILD MODEL
class classification_model(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size):        
        super(classification_model, self).__init__()        
        self.word_emb = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, 
                                                  WORD_EMB_DIM, 
                                                  mask_zero=True, 
                                                  name="word_embedding_layer")               
            
        self.lstm   = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(LSTM_DIM, return_state=True, name="rnn_layer")    
        self.dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2)           
    
    
    def call(self, word_emb_inp, initial_state=None, training=True):   
        word_emb = self.word_emb(word_emb_inp)                           # (bs, MAX_LEN, WORD_EMB_DIM)
        word_emb_mask = self.word_emb.compute_mask(word_emb_inp)         # (bs, MAX_LEN)

        lstm_inp = word_emb                                              # (bs, MAX_LEN, WORD_EMB_DIM)
        lstm_inp_mask = word_emb_mask                                    # (bs, MAX_LEN)
                            
        lstm, state_h, state_c = self.lstm(lstm_inp, mask=word_emb_mask, initial_state=initial_state)
        dense_out = self.dense(lstm)
        return dense_out


# INITIALIZING DATASET AND MODEL
dataset = text_dataset()
model = classification_model(dataset.vocab_size)
model.build(input_shape=(None, MAX_LENGTH))
model.summary()

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam() 

loss_func = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(
    from_logits=True,
    name='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'
)


# TRAINING
print("\n")
print("TRAINING")
print("\n")
for e in range(START_EPOCH, END_EPOCH):
    print(f"EPOCH: {str(e+1).zfill(len(str(END_EPOCH)))}/{END_EPOCH}")

    train_gen  = dataset.data_generator
    train_gen = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
                            train_gen,
                            output_types=(tf.dtypes.int64, tf.dtypes.int64),
                            output_shapes=((None, MAX_LENGTH), (None,)) 
                            )   

    for batch_idx, batch in enumerate(train_gen): 
        # print(batch_idx, type(batch))
        # print(batch[0].shape, batch[1].shape)
        x, y = batch

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            logits = model(x) # model is supposed to output the logits (BATCH_SIZE, 2)

            loss_value = loss_func(y, logits)

            print(loss_value.numpy(), end="\r")
            grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_variables)
            optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))
    
    print(f"loss@epoch#{e}: {loss_value.numpy()}")


# EXPORT MODEL
print("\nEXPORTING THE MODEL\n")
tf.saved_model.save(model, 
                    export_dir=SAVE_MODEL_PATH,
                    signatures=None)

# IMPORTING MODEL
imported = tf.saved_model.load(SAVE_MODEL_PATH)
print(type(imported))
pprint(imported.signatures)

inp = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3, 0, 0]])
out = imported(inp)
print("out: ", out)
```

I have multiple issues here-

- How to export vocabulary?
- How to access the saved vocabulary?
- How to handle text preprocessing while exporting and importing the model?
- How to make predictions after importing the model?

This is how things look after I run the code from the part I am loading the model-

```
2021-10-14 22:52:32.754962: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2021-10-14 22:52:37.487561: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2021-10-14 22:52:38.559793: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1733] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 1660 Ti computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.59GHz coreCount: 24 deviceMemorySize: 6.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 268.26GiB/s
2021-10-14 22:52:38.560014: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2021-10-14 22:52:38.567645: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2021-10-14 22:52:38.567785: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2021-10-14 22:52:38.572346: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-10-14 22:52:38.573904: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-10-14 22:52:38.583016: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_11.dll
2021-10-14 22:52:38.586465: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_11.dll
2021-10-14 22:52:38.587604: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
2021-10-14 22:52:38.587822: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1871] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-10-14 22:52:38.588323: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021-10-14 22:52:38.589853: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1733] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 1660 Ti computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.59GHz coreCount: 24 deviceMemorySize: 6.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 268.26GiB/s
2021-10-14 22:52:38.590197: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1871] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-10-14 22:52:39.163026: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1258] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-10-14 22:52:39.163216: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1264]      0
2021-10-14 22:52:39.163535: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1277] 0:   N
2021-10-14 22:52:39.163842: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1418] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 3983 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1660 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
2021-10-14 22:52:40.735500: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/graph_constructor.cc:809] Node 'cond/while' has 13 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 46 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2021-10-14 22:52:40.793113: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/graph_constructor.cc:809] Node 'cond/while' has 13 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 46 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2021-10-14 22:52:40.975299: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/graph_constructor.cc:809] Node 'cond' has 5 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 46 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2021-10-14 22:52:41.209622: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/graph_constructor.cc:809] Node 'cond/while' has 13 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 46 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2021-10-14 22:52:42.214461: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/graph_constructor.cc:809] Node 'cond' has 5 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 46 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2021-10-14 22:52:42.421412: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/graph_constructor.cc:809] Node 'cond' has 5 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 46 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2021-10-14 22:52:42.698141: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/graph_constructor.cc:809] Node 'cond/while' has 13 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 46 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2021-10-14 22:52:46.216757: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/graph_constructor.cc:809] Node 'cond/while' has 13 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 46 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2021-10-14 22:52:46.891681: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/graph_constructor.cc:809] Node 'cond/while' has 13 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 46 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2021-10-14 22:52:46.922376: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/graph_constructor.cc:809] Node 'cond' has 5 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 46 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2021-10-14 22:52:47.696619: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/graph_constructor.cc:809] Node 'cond/while' has 13 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 46 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2021-10-14 22:52:47.726003: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/graph_constructor.cc:809] Node 'cond' has 5 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 46 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2021-10-14 22:52:47.818013: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/graph_constructor.cc:809] Node 'cond/while' has 13 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 46 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2021-10-14 22:52:47.847961: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/graph_constructor.cc:809] Node 'cond' has 5 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 46 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2021-10-14 22:52:48.188927: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/graph_constructor.cc:809] Node 'cond/while' has 13 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 46 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2021-10-14 22:52:48.220841: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/graph_constructor.cc:809] Node 'cond' has 5 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 46 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2021-10-14 22:52:48.281547: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/graph_constructor.cc:809] Node 'cond' has 5 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 46 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2021-10-14 22:52:48.382800: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/graph_constructor.cc:809] Node 'cond' has 5 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 46 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
<class 'tensorflow.python.saved_model.load.Loader._recreate_base_user_object.<locals>._UserObject'>
_SignatureMap({'serving_default': <ConcreteFunction signature_wrapper(*, input_1) at 0x1AEB12589A0>})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\daftar\tensorflow_serving\load.py", line 13, in <module>
    out = imported(inp)
  File "C:\Users\anime\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\load.py", line 670, in _call_attribute
    return instance.__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\anime\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 889, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\anime\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 933, in _call
    self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
  File "C:\Users\anime\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 763, in _initialize
    self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "C:\Users\anime\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 3050, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\anime\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 3444, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\anime\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 3279, in _create_graph_function
    func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
  File "C:\Users\anime\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 999, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\anime\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 672, in wrapped_fn
    out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\anime\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\function_deserialization.py", line 285, in restored_function_body
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Could not find matching function to call loaded from the SavedModel. Got:
  Positional arguments (3 total):
    * Tensor("song_emb_inp:0", shape=(1, 5), dtype=int32)
    * None
    * True
  Keyword arguments: {}

Expected these arguments to match one of the following 4 option(s):

Option 1:
  Positional arguments (3 total):
    * TensorSpec(shape=(None, 5), dtype=tf.int64, name='input_1')
    * None
    * False
  Keyword arguments: {}

Option 2:
  Positional arguments (3 total):
    * TensorSpec(shape=(None, 5), dtype=tf.int64, name='song_emb_inp')
    * None
    * False
  Keyword arguments: {}

Option 3:
  Positional arguments (3 total):
    * TensorSpec(shape=(None, 5), dtype=tf.int64, name='song_emb_inp')
    * None
    * True
  Keyword arguments: {}

Option 4:
  Positional arguments (3 total):
    * TensorSpec(shape=(None, 5), dtype=tf.int64, name='input_1')
    * None
    * True
  Keyword arguments: {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I had to define input_signatures to the methods that I would be calling after importing an exported model.

```
import tensorflow as tf
print("tf.__version__: ", tf.__version__)
import os, sys, random, pdb
from pprint import pprint
import numpy as np

START_EPOCH = 0 
END_EPOCH = 3
MAX_LENGTH = 5
BATCH_SIZE = 512
WORD_EMB_DIM = 32
LSTM_DIM=4
SAVE_MODEL_PATH = "saved_models/1"

def q(exit_msg=""):
    print(f"\n>{exit_msg}<")
    sys.exit()

text_data = [
        "i like this movie",
        "i feel happy watch movie",
        "great taste",
        "like the look of it",
        "great news",
        "hate this movie",
        "very bad news",
        "horrible movie",
        "very bad news",
        "i do not like it"
        ]

label_data = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]


# BUILD DATASET
class text_dataset():
    def __init__(self):
        self._build_vocab_list()
        
    def _build_vocab_list(self):
        words = []
        for words_list in [t.split(" ") for t in text_data]:
            words.extend(words_list)
        words = sorted(list(set(words)))
        self.vocab_list = words    
        print(f"len of vocab_list: {len(self.vocab_list)}")


    def build_vocab_mapping_from_tokenizer(self, tokenizer_vocab_list):
        self.item2idx = {w: w_idx for w_idx, w in enumerate(tokenizer_vocab_list)}
        self.idx2item = {w_idx: w for w_idx, w in enumerate(tokenizer_vocab_list)}
        print(f"len of tokenizer_vocab_list: {len(self.idx2item)}")

    def data_generator(self):
        batch_idx = 0
        while batch_idx < 64:
            sample_indices = [random.randint(0, len(text_data)-1) for _ in range(BATCH_SIZE)]

            x_raw = [text_data[i] for i in sample_indices]
            y = [label_data[i] for i in sample_indices]
            yield tuple((x_raw, y))
            batch_idx += 1


# BUILD MODEL
class classification_model(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, vocab_list):        
        super(classification_model, self).__init__()   

        # self.input_layer = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.string)
        self.vectorize_layer = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization(
                                      max_tokens=None, 
                                      standardize='lower_and_strip_punctuation',
                                      split='whitespace', ngrams=None, 
                                      output_mode='int', output_sequence_length=None, 
                                      pad_to_max_tokens=False, vocabulary=vocab_list)
        
        self.word_emb = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(len(self.vectorize_layer.get_vocabulary()), 
                                                  WORD_EMB_DIM, 
                                                  mask_zero=True, 
                                                  name="word_embedding_layer")               
            
        self.lstm   = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(LSTM_DIM, return_state=True, name="rnn_layer")    
        self.dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2)           

    @tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None], dtype=tf.string)])
    def get_tokens_indices(self, inp_string):   
      return self.vectorize_layer(inp_string)

    # @tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None), dtype=tf.string),
    #                               tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, LSTM_DIM), dtype=tf.float32),
    #                               tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, LSTM_DIM), dtype=tf.float32)])
    @tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None], dtype=tf.string), 
                                  tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None, LSTM_DIM], dtype=tf.float32), 
                                  tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None, LSTM_DIM], dtype=tf.float32)])
    def call(self, inp_string, state_h, state_c):   

        word_emb_inp = self.vectorize_layer(inp_string)
        word_emb = self.word_emb(word_emb_inp)                           # (bs, MAX_LEN, WORD_EMB_DIM)
        word_emb_mask = self.word_emb.compute_mask(word_emb_inp)         # (bs, MAX_LEN)

        lstm_inp = word_emb                                              # (bs, MAX_LEN, WORD_EMB_DIM)
        lstm_inp_mask = word_emb_mask                                    # (bs, MAX_LEN)
                            
        lstm, state_h, state_c = self.lstm(lstm_inp, mask=word_emb_mask, initial_state=[state_h, state_c])
        dense_out = self.dense(lstm)
        return dense_out, state_h, state_c


# INITIALIZING DATASET AND MODEL
dataset = text_dataset()
model = classification_model(dataset.vocab_list)
# print(help(model.build))
# model.build(input_shape=(None, MAX_LENGTH))
# model.summary()

tokenizer_vocab_list = model.vectorize_layer.get_vocabulary()
# print("tokenizer_vocab_list: ", tokenizer_vocab_list)

dataset.build_vocab_mapping_from_tokenizer(tokenizer_vocab_list)
# item2idx = dataset.item2idx
# idx2item = dataset.idx2item
# pprint(item2idx)
# pprint(idx2item)

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam() 

loss_func = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(
    from_logits=True,
    name='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'
    )

# TRAINING
print("\nTRAINING\n")
for e in range(START_EPOCH, END_EPOCH):
    print(f"EPOCH: {str(e+1).zfill(len(str(END_EPOCH)))}/{END_EPOCH}")

    train_gen  = dataset.data_generator
    train_gen = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
                            train_gen,
                            output_types=(tf.dtypes.string, tf.dtypes.int32),
                            output_shapes=((None,), (None,)) 
                            )   

    for batch_idx, batch in enumerate(train_gen): 
        x, y = batch
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            zero_state_h_tensor = tf.zeros((BATCH_SIZE, LSTM_DIM), dtype=tf.dtypes.float32)
            zero_state_c_tensor = tf.zeros((BATCH_SIZE, LSTM_DIM), dtype=tf.dtypes.float32)
            logits, _, _ = model(x, zero_state_h_tensor, zero_state_c_tensor)#, zero_state_tensors, zero_state_tensors) # model is supposed to output the logits (BATCH_SIZE, 2)
            loss_value = loss_func(y, logits)
            print(loss_value.numpy(), end="\r")
            grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_variables)
            optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))
    
    print(f"loss@epoch#{e}: {loss_value.numpy()}")


    print("\nEXPORTING THE MODEL...")
class MyModule(tf.Module):
  def __init__(self, model, item2idx):
    self.model = model
    self.this = json.loads(item2idx)

  @tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None), dtype=tf.string),
                                tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, LSTM_DIM), dtype=tf.float32),
                                tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, LSTM_DIM), dtype=tf.float32)])
  def predict(self, inp_string, state_h, state_c):
    # tokenized_input = self.model.vectorize_layer(inp_string) # doesnt work
    tokenized_input = self.model.get_tokens_indices(inp_string)
    result, state_h, state_c = self.model(inp_string, state_h, state_c)
    return {"scores": result, 
            "state_h": state_h,
            "state_c": state_c,
            "tokenized_input": tokenized_input
            }

  @tf.function(input_signature=[])
  def metadata(self):
    return {"item2idx": item2idx}

import json

item2idx = json.dumps(dataset.item2idx)
module = MyModule(model, item2idx)
tf.saved_model.save(module, 
                    SAVE_MODEL_PATH, 
                    signatures={ "predict": module.predict, 
                                #  "preprocess": module.preprocess,
                                 "metadata": module.metadata})


print("\nIMPORTING THE MODEL...")
imported = tf.saved_model.load(SAVE_MODEL_PATH)

imported_item2idx = imported.signatures["metadata"]()["item2idx"]
json.loads(imported_item2idx.numpy())
  
test_text = "movie was"

print("test_text: ", test_text)

def get_zero_state_tensor():
  return tf.zeros((1, LSTM_DIM), dtype=tf.dtypes.float32)

state_h = get_zero_state_tensor()
state_c = get_zero_state_tensor()

inp = tf.constant([test_text], dtype=tf.string)
out = imported.signatures["predict"](inp_string=inp, state_h=state_h, state_c=state_c)#, initial_state=initial_state)#, initial_state)#["scores"].numpy()
print("\nout")
pprint(out)
```